# Multiples of 3 and 5, multiples of 5 and multiples of 3 in Java

Tags: java

I have a school assignment that says:

Given a integer print out the integer, but for multiples of 3 print “Computer” instead of the integer and for the multiples of 5 print “Science”. For integers which are multiples of both 3 and 5 print “CS”. For the given example, create a class called NumberPrinter. Create a method that for a given integer prints out what the example states. In the main method prompt the user for the integer, and store that integer in a class variable.

Note: You can use integers with mod to check if a number is a multiple

We do not need loops.  If the user inputs the number, only inputs multiples of 15, it will display "CS", "Computer" for multiples of 5 and "Science" for multiples of 3.  My code compiles, but every number I choose gives an output of CS.  I've been stumped on this for two days.  Can anyone help me?  Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class ComputerScience {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create instance of Scanner
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);



        // Prompt user for a number
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        int number = scanner.nextInt(); // Declare number variable
        System.out.println(); // Print out a blank line

        // Instance if statements using number from isNumber method
            if (isNumber(number %  5 & number % 3)) {
                System.out.println("CS "); // Prints CS if number is a multiple of 3 and 5
            } else {
                if (isNumber(number % 5)) {
                    System.out.println("Science "); // Prints "Science" if number is a multiple of 5
                    } else {
                        if (isNumber(number % 3)) {
                        System.out.println("Computer "); // Prints "Computer if number is a multiple of 3
                        } else {
                            if (isNumber(number)){
                                System.out.println("");
                                } else {
                                    if (number <= 0){
                                    System.out.println("Please use a positive number only.");
                                    } // End if
                            } // End if
                        } // End if
                } // End if
            } // End if
    } // End method main


    // Method isNumber to return value with if statements


    public static boolean isNumber(int value) {
        if (value % 5 == 0 && value % 3 == 0) { // if statement for multiples of 3 and 5
            return value % 5 == 0 && value % 3 == 0; // return multiples of 15
            } else {
                if (value % 5 == 0) { //  if statement for multiples of 5
                    return value % 5 == 0; // return multiples of 5
                    } else {
                        if (value % 3 == 0) { // if statement for multiples of 3
                            return value % 3 == 0; // return value
                            } else {
                                return value == 0;
                        } // End if
                } // End if
        } // End if
    } // End isNumber method
} // End program
```

Comment: Fizzbuzz.................

Comment: Re-read your code, you are writing a lot of unnecesseray lines. What is the purpose of `isNumber` method ? Also check what modulo is because it's not what you think..

Comment: I know it can be solved easily without a method, but it said to create a method.  I think it's unnecessary too, but we're told to create a method for it so we can get more comfortable with them.

Comment: I already looked at the Fizzbuzz examples, but it's not helping me with the method.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have specified the desired output of the modulus . So at then end of the if statement it should be something like `if(number %3 ==0 )` you have to include ==0 to refer to divisibility so add ==0 at the end of the mod statements .

Comment: Also note that `a & b` is not the same as `a && b` (check your first `if`).

Comment: I added the ==0 like you said, but it gave me an errors when I instance the method isNumber in the main method.   It said that the int variable for value is not compatible with the boolean statements when I add them.  I also tried to change the variable value to boolean and then I got different errors.